# confirm delete swal not functioning

Tags: javascript, php

[The swal stays that way infinetly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq5Mc.jpg)
I am new to javascript. I am using swal to confirm delete of an order. the order is deleted correctly from the database and when I reload the page, I find the order deleted but the thing is that the page is not reloaded automatically.

```
echo ($paid == 0) ? "<td><p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-confirm' id='" . $orderId . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></p></td>" : "<td></td>";


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-confirm').on('click', function() {
var orderId = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(orderId);
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "If you delete this post all associated comments also deleted permanently.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.post("delete.php", {
        id: orderId
      },
      function(data, status) {
        swal({
          title: "Deleted!",
          text: "Your post has been deleted.",
          type: "success"
        },
          function() {
            location.reload();
          }
        );
      }
    );

  }, 50);
});
});
</script>
<script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

and the delete.php is here

```
<?php

session_start();
include('config.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: login.php");
}

$orderId = $_POST['id'];
$qry = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id ='$orderId'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$qry);
```

?>

The order is deleted successfully from the database and the swal is not closed even if i wait infinite time and the page is not getting reloaded. 
Please help me.

Comment: Anyone has got an answer

Comment: Be careful. Someone could send a SQL instead of the ID ... It's often better to use prepared statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Which version of swal do you use?

Why are you using setTimeout, what are you waiting for?

I also use swal as deletion confirmation in the following way:

```
swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "If you delete this post all associated comments also deleted permanently.",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        reverseButtons: true,  
        focusCancel: true,
        confirmButtonText:  "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "cancel"
    })
    .then(  function (willDelete) {
            if (willDelete) {
                 $.post(        "delete.php", 
                               { id: orderId },
                               function(data, status) {
                                  swal({
                                         title: "Deleted!",
                                         text: "Your post has been deleted.",
                                         type: "success"
                                  };
                               }
                        )    
            } else {
                  toastr.info(Texxt('delet canceled), Texxt('Abbruch') + '.', {
                        closeButton: true,
                        progressBar: true,
                    });
            }
    }).catch(swal.noop);
```